# Client side query builder (jquery) to Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I want to ask how can I build a query builder engine same like TFS uses for queries that will allow user to combine multiple conditions and in the backend will use EF in order to query the data based on the conditions.

[image]

Something like: user builds the query -> send json to backend -> backend process query as EF code first + repository pattern.

There is a jquery query builder plugin but how can I convert that json to EF repository pattern?

jQuery Query Builder: [jquery query builder](http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/)

Answer (score 3):

today i wanted to use jquery query builder with EF and i wrote this code for parsing filter to Expression. i hope it useful for others.

rule data model :

```
public class Rule
{
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

and controller class with rule Parser :

```
        public ActionResult GetRole(List<Rule> rules,string condition)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(NgnPacket), "x");
        var rawExp = CreateCondition(rules, condition, param);
        var logic = new NgnMonitoringLogic();
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<NgnPacket, bool>>(rawExp, param);
        var g = logic.GetData(exp);
        return Content(g == null ? "0" : g.Count().ToString());
    }

    private Expression CreateCondition(List<Rule> rules, string conditionOperation, ParameterExpression param)
    {
        Expression temp = null;
        foreach (var rule in rules)
        {
            if (rule.Rules != null && rule.Rules.Any())
            {
                var innerExpression = CreateCondition(rule.Rules, rule.Condition, param);
                if (innerExpression == null) continue;
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    var ruleCondition = string.IsNullOrEmpty(rule.Condition) ? conditionOperation : rule.Condition;
                    temp = ruleCondition.ToLower() == "and"
                              ? Expression.And(temp, innerExpression)
                              : Expression.Or(temp, innerExpression);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = innerExpression;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                Expression lowValue = null;
                Expression highValue = null;
                Expression lowCondition;
                Expression highCondition;

                var property = Expression.Property(param, rule.Id);
                object rawValue = null;
                switch (rule.Type.ToLower())
                {
                    case "string":
                        rawValue = rule.Value.First();
                        break;
                    case "integer":

                        if (rule.Value.Count()==1)
                        {
                            if (property.Type == typeof(int))
                            {
                                rawValue = Convert.ToInt32(rule.Value.First());

                            }
                            else if (property.Type == typeof(long))
                            {
                                rawValue = Convert.ToInt64(rule.Value.First());

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (property.Type == typeof (int))
                            {
                                lowValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToInt32(rule.Value[0]));
                                highValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToInt32(rule.Value[1]));
                            }
                            else if (property.Type == typeof (long))
                            {
                                lowValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToInt64(rule.Value[0]));
                                highValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToInt64(rule.Value[1]));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "double":
                        if (rule.Value.Count() == 1)
                        {
                            if (property.Type == typeof(double))
                            {
                                rawValue = Convert.ToDouble(rule.Value.First());

                            }
                            else if (property.Type == typeof(decimal))
                            {
                                rawValue = Convert.ToDecimal(rule.Value.First());

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (property.Type == typeof(double))
                            {
                                lowValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDouble(rule.Value[0]));
                                highValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDouble(rule.Value[1]));
                            }
                            else if (property.Type == typeof(decimal))
                            {
                                lowValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDecimal(rule.Value[0]));
                                highValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDecimal(rule.Value[1]));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "date":
                    case "time":
                    case "datetime":
                        if (rule.Value.Count() == 1)
                        {

                                rawValue = Convert.ToDateTime(rule.Value.First());


                        }
                        else
                        {

                                lowValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDateTime(rule.Value[0]));
                                highValue = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDateTime(rule.Value[1]));


                        }
                        break;                         
                    case "boolean":

                        rawValue = Convert.ToBoolean(rule.Value);

                        break;
                }
                var value = Expression.Constant(rawValue);
                Expression condition = null;
                string m = null;

                var containsMethod = rule.Type == "string" ? typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }) : typeof(IList).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });


                switch (rule.Operator.ToLower())
                {
                    case "equal":
                        condition = Expression.Equal(property, value);
                        break;
                    case "not_equal":
                        condition = Expression.NotEqual(property, value);
                        break;
                    case "in":
                    case "contains":
                        condition = Expression.Call(property, containsMethod, value);
                        break;
                    case "not_in":
                    case "not_contains":
                        condition = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(property, containsMethod, value));
                        break;
                    case "less":
                        condition = Expression.LessThan(property, value);
                        break;
                    case "less_or_equal":
                        condition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, value);
                        break;
                    case "greater":
                        condition = Expression.GreaterThan(property, value);
                        break;
                    case "greater_or_equal":
                        condition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, value);
                        break;
                    case "between":
                        lowCondition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, lowValue);
                        highCondition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, highValue);
                        condition = Expression.AndAlso(lowCondition, highCondition);
                        break;
                    case "not_between":
                        lowCondition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, lowValue);
                        highCondition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, highValue);
                        condition = Expression.Not(Expression.AndAlso(lowCondition, highCondition));
                        break;
                    case "begins_with":
                        throw new Exception("Operation BeginWith is not implemented..");
                    case "not_begins_with":
                        throw new Exception("Operation Not BeginWith is not implemented..");
                    case "ends_with":
                        throw new Exception("Operation Not ends_with is not implemented..");
                    case "not_ends_with":
                        throw new Exception("Operation Not not_ends_with is not implemented..");
                    case "is_empty":
                        condition = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(""));
                        break;
                    case "is_not_empty":
                        condition = Expression.NotEqual(property, Expression.Constant(""));
                        break;
                    case "is_null":
                        condition = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(null));
                        break;
                    case "is_not_null":
                        condition = Expression.NotEqual(property, Expression.Constant(null));
                        break;
                }
                if (condition == null) continue;
                ;
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    var ruleCondition = string.IsNullOrEmpty(rule.Condition) ? conditionOperation : rule.Condition;
                    temp = ruleCondition.ToLower() == "and"
                        ? Expression.And(temp, condition)
                        : Expression.Or(temp, condition);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = condition;
                }
            }
        }
        return temp;


    }
```

Comment: What are NgnPacket and NgnMonitoringLogic?

Comment: @calvin NgnPacket is my entity and NgnMonitoringLogic is a bussiness Logic Layer

Comment: @MahdiFarhani I'm using SqlCommand(). Can this function also generate conditions in text or something can be used with CommandText with select statement ?

Comment: @Prince Rathee this function can not generate SQL Command but Jquery Query builder has a plugin can generate SQL text command

Comment: @MahdiFarhani Oops, exposing SQL on front-end using Jquery is unsafe unfortunately. Any other way? Here was my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823665/dynamically-build-a-sql-where-clause-from-c-sharp-objects/38823947

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to suggest you to use the MVC 5 Api . Its binding engines is smart enough to map Json as an View model object( It's your class wich represents the json object) after that you can use AutoMapper Library to proceed that object to server entities and send them to DAL where ef will do the work.

Comment: OP's question is _"how can I convert that json to EF repository pattern?"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I suggested the way. He can wrap the json data from plugin with ViewModel classes and than use them as he wants. And for the binding from jquery i suggested asp.net mvc 5 api, that binds json data perfectly.