# Dynamically build a SQL WHERE clause from c# Objects

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I am creating filters in my HTML table binded with asp.net web API using HTTP POST request and using this [jquery querybuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html) to create filters.

```
{
 "condition": "AND",
 "rules": [
   {
     "id": "price",
     "field": "price",
     "type": "double",
     "input": "text",
     "operator": "less",
     "value": "10.25"
   },
   {
     "condition": "OR",
     "rules": [
       {
         "id": "category",
         "field": "category",
         "type": "integer",
         "input": "select",
         "operator": "equal",
         "value": "2"
       },
       {
         "id": "category",
         "field": "category",
         "type": "integer",
         "input": "select",
         "operator": "equal",
         "value": "1"
       }]
   }]
}
```

Is there any way I can convert this JSON object in where conditions using C# or any other nuget package which can receive the HTTP post objects and filter the data in SQL?

**C#**

```
public Products GetProductById(object filterObj)  
 {  
     SqlDataReader reader = null;  
     SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();  
     myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=.\SQLSERVER2008R2;Database=DBCompany;User ID=sa;Password=xyz@1234;";  

     SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();  
     sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  
     sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE PRICE < 10.25 AND (CATEGORY = 2 OR CATEGORY = 1);  
     sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;  
     myConnection.Open();  
     reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();  
     Products prod = null;  
     while (reader.Read())  
     {  
         prod = new Products ();  
         prod.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));  
         prod.Name = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();  
         prod.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(2));  
     }  
     return prod ;  

 }
```

Comment: well all the data is there so yes you can convert it into an SQL Query. if you want to do it in c# you could create your own method that decodes it for you.

Comment: are you using an mvc web api?

Comment: Yes I'm using mvc web api with SQL server in backend

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dynamic [Linq Query Builder](https://github.com/castle-it/dynamic-linq-query-builder)

Some example: We are passing rules from jquery querybuilder, than Build query and retrieve relevant data from DB

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Applay(FilterRule obj)
    {
        var messages = context.messages.BuildQuery(obj).ToList();
        return JsonContent(messages);
    }
```

Update:

obj is already deserialized json with filter rules (from jquery querybuilder)
context.messages - is part of Entity Framework context

```
(DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; })
```

In this approach you are building sql query by means of linq and EF translates it to SQL. If you are using ADO.NET than you can try to find relevant example on git hib project page.

Comment: Any working example with SQL server?

Comment: In my example I'm using Entity Framework and MS SQL

Comment: Can you please share more details, where is SQL command, what does obj contains etc?

Comment: Please see the updated question, that's how i pull the data from SQL. Now question is how to implement this solution in my scenario?

Comment: hi @Ilya, I was reading your comment and trying to understand, can you please share a snippet/link or add some info.. on how can I access the EF query

Answer (score 1):

On the QueryBuilder site, the plugins section includes one that can emit SQL from the JavaScript library -

http://querybuilder.js.org/plugins.html

Would that help or do you want to receive json in c# and translate it manually (or with a NuGet package, though I'm not aware of any)? There may be security concerns with passing a SQL clause from the client code to the server to execute..

Comment: Awesome knows of a NuGet package, I think his is a better answer :)

Comment: This SQL on client side is not safe and expose a lots of things to end users. So I wanted to recieve JSON and convert that into my SQL conditions.