# Dynamically build SQL where clause based on presence of attributes in DTO

Tags: java, sql, groovy

I have a screen where users can search a table based on 1 or more of its columns. I am passing the columns the users would like to filter by as a DTO to the backend.

There I am building a SQL to query by checking for the presence of these fields in the DTO...

```
Object transactionSearch (TransactionSearchDTO dto ){

    StringBuilder transactionQuery = new StringBuilder()
    transactionQuery.append("SELECT id, delivery_date, order_date, customer_name FROM transaction where 1=1 ")

    if (dto.order_id) {
     transactionQuery.append("and order_id = ${dto.order_id}")
    }
    if (delivery_date) {
     transactionQuery.append("and order_id = ${delivery_date}")
    }
    if (customer_name) {
     transactionQuery.append("and order_id = ${customer_name}")
    }

}
```

What I am ending up with is a ton of if statements for each column.

Is there a way to achieve this without having an if block per filter?

I found some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823665/dynamically-build-a-sql-where-clause-from-c-sharp-objects) but I need a solution in Groovy or Java.

Comment: Doesn't your example need to be tweaked to not use `order_id` in all three `if` tests?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use GString instead of StringBuilder to pass parameters correctly to groovy.sql.Sql

```
class DTO{
    int id
    String name
    Date created
}

def a = new DTO(id:123, created:new Date())

GString f(DTO a){
    GString q = GString.EMPTY + 'select ' + a.getProperties().collect{k,v-> k}.join(',')+' from T'
    
    a.getProperties().each{k,v->
        if(k!='class' && v!=null){
            q = q + ( q.getValueCount()==0 ? ' WHERE ' : ' AND ' )
            q = q + k + " = ${v}"
        }
    }
    
    return q
}

def s = f(a)

println s
println s.getValues()
println s.getStrings()
```